# Changes have lost on mirrored volume

Tags: 18.04, lvm

I have a 512GB mirrored volume, which has a snapshot on the volume of same size:

```
  LV          VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  mirror      vg1 owi-a-r-r- 512,00g                                    100,00
  mirror-snap vg1 swi-aos--- 512,00g      mirror 3,98
  storage     vg1 -wi-ao----  <2,14t
```

The mirror was created on 08.03.2020:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg1/mirror
  LV Name                mirror
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                v9x643-ZVZR-3QnQ-Zjud-HR3t-zVeU-XXZNTz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time sandlet, 2020-03-08 18:23:00 +0100
  LV snapshot status     source of
                         mirror-snap [active]
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                512,00 GiB
  Current LE             131072
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:8
```

The snapshot was created

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg1/mirror-snap
  LV Name                mirror-snap
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                CkdK28-4gN4-zvg7-cTHm-fEBk-p2oX-Hb7Hi6
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time sandlet, 2020-03-14 18:24:14 +0100
  LV snapshot status     active destination for mirror
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                512,00 GiB
  Current LE             131072
  COW-table size         512,00 GiB
  COW-table LE           131073
  Allocated to snapshot  3,98%
  Snapshot chunk size    4,00 KiB
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:10
```

Yesterday I've rebooted the computer. Reboot took rather long (about 10 minutes). After it was rebooted I've noticed the data on the mirror volume isn't current but rather more than month old. Specifically I've noticed in databases last records are the ones, which were added on 28.03.2020. 
I haven't noticed any specific indication of the issue in the logs except may be this:

```
[    2.225665] device-mapper: raid: Loading target version 1.14.0 [   
2.229924] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (2 bytes read) [    2.252783] device-mapper: raid: Failed to read superblock of device at position 0 [    2.281819] md: personality for level 1 is not loaded! [
2.281839] device-mapper: table: 253:6: raid: Failed to run raid array [    2.281841] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table [   
2.288362] device-mapper: raid: Failed to read superblock of device at position 0 [    2.289252] md: personality for level 1 is not loaded! [
2.289260] device-mapper: table: 253:6: raid: Failed to run raid array [    2.289261] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table ... [    3.964926] device-mapper: raid: Failed to read superblock of device at position 0 [    3.976202] md/raid1:mdX: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
```

and the fact the file system was mounted quite long:

```
[    4.713429] EXT4-fs (dm-6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[  208.170013] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:404D.0004: HID++ 4.1 device connected.
[  282.781954] EXT4-fs (dm-10): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

also this entry looks weird but I'm not sure it's related:

```
[  289.392877] rfkill: input handler disabled
[20462.471539] perf: interrupt took too long (2502 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[21821.858690] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4057.0005: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[21985.454154] rfkill: input handler enabled
[21997.746672] rfkill: input handler disabled
[22263.335187] perf: interrupt took too long (3144 > 3127), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
[23750.728687] perf: interrupt took too long (3934 > 3930), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50750
[44992.958039] perf: interrupt took too long (4918 > 4917), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40500
```

Disks on which the mirror is built are old ones. But same disks have another spanned volume and that one has no problems.
What could happen with the mirror and is there a way to prevent this? I'm not talking about restoring lost data - it's unpleasant but not critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my lack of knowledge of LVM didn't let me see the cause at the very beginning:

```
  LV          VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  mirror      vg1 owi-a-r-r- 512,00g                                    100,00
  mirror-snap vg1 swi-aos--- 512,00g      mirror 3,98
```

6th symbol "o" in attributes shows the volume is open. man lvs explains the term "open" no further. But from circumstances it's obvious open volume is the one, which is mounted.

Indeed my snapshot volume was mounted instead of original one to the same mount point and therefore I saw old volume state instead of current one.

There is still a question why snapshot state wasn't of its creation date (14.03) but 2 weeks later (28.03) as well as why snapshot was mounted instead of origin and even after consequential reboots. But currently I don't want to spend any more time on that.